# How can I delete a file with permission 444?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, permissions, apache2

My server is running Ubuntu 18.04.

I have a file in `vestacp` that I cannot delete. This file contains malware and has permission 444 and when I try to delete it using `sudo rm -rf file` or even change permissions using `sudo chmod 777` it just does nothing.

I also cannot edit the file at all. I even changed ownership using `chown admin:admin` but nothing is happening.

Comment: Do the `rm` and `chmod` commands work OK on other files?

Comment: You can always delete a stubborn file from a live system.

Comment: Please do an `ls -l {file}` and add the results to the question. Without it is is going to impossible to answer. For all we know you added +i to the attributes.

Comment: "when I try to delete it [...] it just does nothing", do you mean there's no error message? Can you run `ls -il filename` before and after you run the `rm` command? If the file is malware as you mention, I suspect it either has some special or hidden characters in its file name, or the file is being recreated after every delete.

Comment: `-r--r--r--  1 admin admin     0 Sep 16 10:46 index.php` This is the result of command @Dan
@FedonKadifeli yes those commands work on other files. It is just this file that is stubborn. 

@guillermochamorro It is on a live server.

Answer (score 0):

Ideas:

1. some process may use the file, with `lsof` you can look, which process has it locked:

```
$ lsof | grep vestacp
```

If you see the process, you should kill it first and then try to delete the file.

2. Reboot, choose in grub menu recovery option and try to delete the file.

Comment: There is no process from vesta. I actually first thought there was a script or process that was recreating this file, but there is none.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `admin` in linux. The user you're looking for is `root`.

Locally `root` may do everything technically possible. You can even delete your whole filesystem including your operating system. So be careful!

So as long as you're in the context of user `root` it's no issue to delete a local file you don't have any permissions to.

Just do:

> ```
> rm YOURFILE
> ```

Comment: it is on a live server running vestacp. but even when i use root, the file is still there... The `rm filename` command does not work either. the file is still there.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a issue like this a long time ago and this commands below helped

without super user privileges 
`ls file_to_be_delete | xargs /bin/rm --force`

With super user privileges 
`ls file_to_be_delete | sudo xargs /bin/rm --force`

Comment: I have tried this and the file is still there

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the answers above, though promising and well researched, none seemed to stick for long. I finally resolved to changing the ownership of these files to root using `chown -R root:root folder` or without `-R`  for a file. This then makes editing difficult for any user, including **admin** which was the main problem.
Now for me to make any changes, I either use terminal or change the ownership to admin after that I return it to root.